# How to capture VEVO videos through playlistItens?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a question related to capturing VEVO videos on artist channels.
 When I make a request to the API via the playlist, these VEVO videos don't appear in the channel's video list

example:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet
           &maxResults=30&orderby=time&playlistId={UUnJoUTYXU142gxoyDzp-KRQ}&key={api_key}
```

Another playlist id where this occurs {UC4WvVh0AwJ6K9w1JLepce7A}

I tried to use videoSyndicated and videoEmbeddable a few times, but none of them proved effective in the case.

Can you help with any suggestions to work around this problem?

Thankful (:

Comment: While [UUnJoUTYXU142gxoyDzp-KRQ](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=UUnJoUTYXU142gxoyDzp-KRQ) loads correctly, [UC4WvVh0AwJ6K9w1JLepce7A](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=UC4WvVh0AwJ6K9w1JLepce7A) doesn't load correctly. I don't find any VEVO videos in the playlist [UUnJoUTYXU142gxoyDzp-KRQ](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=UUnJoUTYXU142gxoyDzp-KRQ) by the way, can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?